# How to generate "fake" rows in PostgreSQL to use for d3.js

Tags: sql, postgresql, d3.js

i have a query that compares date but the problem i need the column name to be a row.
This the query i have:

```
SELECT
ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage)
   FILTER (WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-04-01') , 2) AS avg_march,
ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage)
   FILTER (WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-05-01'), 2) AS avg_april
```

FROM dashboard.availability
WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-05-01';

as you can see I'm comparing the result of the average percentage on march and april but the problem is the avg_march and avg_april are column names. I need it to be a row result so that i can convert it to JSON and use it on D3.js on a bar chart.

```
avg_march    avg_april
_________    _________
 98.28        95.60
```

but the result i need is:

```
month        average 
_________    _______
avg_march     98.28
avg_april     95.60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHqQ9xUHgyWhhqYtC72MHY/0).

```
SELECT
   unnest(array['avg_march', 'avg_april']) AS months,
   unnest(array[avg_march, avg_april]) AS values
FROM myTable
```

Output:

```
| months    | values |
| --------- | ------ |
| avg_march | 98.28  |
| avg_april | 95.6   |
```

You can try with `crosstab()` as well

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select *
from crosstab
(
  'select *
  from myTable'
) as ct(months text, values float)
```

Comment: But the values is dictated by the formula `ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage)`. It's not defined in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer by the way. I tried doing it like this with the help of your answer:

`SELECT
   unnest(array['avg_march', 'avg_april']) AS months,
   unnest(array[avg_march, avg_april]) AS values
FROM(
 SELECT
  ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage)
     FILTER (WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-04-01') , 2) AS avg_march,
  ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage)
     FILTER (WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-05-01'), 2) AS avg_april
 FROM dashboard.availability
WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-05-01'
 )t`